# Getting the puppet module pcfens/filebeat to work

Tags: ruby, module, logstash, puppet, filebeat

I'm new to this site and puppet. I'm trying so setup a puppet module for filebeat. I want Linux nodes to send logs to logstash using this [module](https://forge.puppet.com/pcfens/filebeat)

I want a configuration that looks something like this:

```
class { 'filebeat':
  outputs => {
    'logstash'     => {
     'hosts' => [
       '<FQDN>:5044',
     ],
     'enabled' => true,
    },
  },
}


filebeat::prospector { 'syslogs':
  paths    => [
    '/var/log/*.log',
    '/var/log/messages',
  ],
  doc_type => 'syslog-beat',
}
```

Does anyone have any experience with this module or with Puppet in general and can tell me how to configure this module with the configuration above. I feel clueless right now and I can't seem to find a lot of documentation about this module. I would really appreciate a push into the right direction on how to setup this module.

Comment: Are you asking how to use Puppet?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I'm not sure, I'm asking how to use this module in Puppet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to ask about how to start your [Control Repo](https://github.com/puppetlabs/control-repo). But before you do that, make sure you read up on the [Roles and Profiles](https://docs.puppet.com/pe/2017.2/r_n_p_intro.html) design pattern.

To get you started, you will have start something like this:

```
$ tree 
.
└── modules
    ├── profile
    │   └── manifests
    │       ├── base
    │       │   └── filebeat.pp
    │       └── base.pp
    └── role
        └── manifests
            ├── base
            └── myrole.pp

7 directories, 3 files
```

(Obviously, as you can see from the example I linked above, it is going to have a lot more in it eventually.)

Then your base class:

```
$ cat modules/profile/manifests/base.pp 
class profile::base {
  include profile::base::filebeat
}
```

Which includes (the code you wrote above):

```
$ cat modules/profile/manifests/base/filebeat.pp 
class profile::base::filebeat {
  class { 'filebeat':
    outputs => {
      'logstash'     => {
       'hosts' => [
         '<FQDN>:5044',
       ],
       'enabled' => true,
      },
    },
  }

  filebeat::prospector { 'syslogs':
    paths => [
      '/var/log/*.log',
      '/var/log/messages',
    ],
    doc_type => 'syslog-beat',
  }
}
```

Your role:

```
$ cat modules/role/manifests/myrole.pp 
class role::myrole {
  include profile::base
}
```

Now, you can test the code on the local host just by ensuring that your modules directory gets copied one way or another into Puppet's [modulepath](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/dirs_modulepath.html).

If so, try:

```
# puppet module install pcfens/filebeat
# puppet apply -e 'include role::myrole'
```

Providing you installed Puppet correctly, and your code above is correct, that would get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm going to do some research on roles and profiles since I'm not familiar with this concept yet. So far I have been editing modules with the puppet files in the modules themselves and linking the modules trough classes and groups on the dashboard.